# Newline between beamerboxesrounded and itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize

In `Beamer` class, I try to put an `itemize` within `beamerboxesrounded`. Now when I try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{beamerboxesrounded}
        % Add a newline here
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item $\ldots$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{beamerboxesrounded}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it gives an error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \end{frame}`. But when I put leave the commented line empty, it works fine. I am curious to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you forgot the mandatory argument (even if empty) for the `beamerboxesrounded` environment. This will work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{beamerboxesrounded}{}
        % Add a newline here
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item $\ldots$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{beamerboxesrounded}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The syntax for the environment is

```
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[<options>]{<head>}
contents
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
```

Comment: Where can I read about the options of `beamerboxesrounded`? For example selecting color of the title font.